# Textbox is not set the value on document.ready in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to set a input type textBox value with dropdownlist selected value on `$(document).ready()` in MVC but it's not filling that value while its works on  `dropdownChange`.

```html
<input type="text" id="acctName" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; height: 22px;" />
```

```js
// Not working
$(function() {
  var accountCode = String('@ViewBag.AccountCode');
  $("#dropdownList option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == accountCode) {
      $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
      $('#acctName')[0].value = $(this).val();
    }
  });
})

// Working
$('#dropdownList').change(function() {
  $('#acctName')[0].value = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure a value is being output from `@ViewBag.AccountCode`? Does it match any of the `option` values? You also don't need `[0].value = ...` just use `val()` on the jQuery object you already have a reference to. That said, it makes more sense to build a `SelectListFor()` and provide the default selected value from the server.

Comment: What is the point of the first script. Just set the value of the property your binding the textbox to in the GET method (or you could just use `value="@ViewBag.AccountCode` in the input

Comment: @ViewBag.AccountCode getting a code value while I want to set the text value of that code .

Comment: you can debug it. if you are using chrome Press F12 OR you want write debugger in your code.

Comment: In @ViewBag.AccountCode a number value is coming and I want to set the name of that code in textBox . Name is also coming in $(this).val(); but its not showing in textBox

Comment: if your are getting text in $(this).val(), then you can use `$('#acctName').val($(this).val());`

Comment: @AsifRaza I can debug and i can see also the value of $(this).val(); .

Comment: irsha_D $('#acctName').val($(this).val()) and  $('#acctName')[0].value = $(this).val(); not working here. I don't know why?

Comment: While  $('#acctName')[0].value = $(this).val(); works on dropdown change event